# PrimeFaces Datatable Column Sorting is not working in IE8 but it works fine in Firefox

Tags: facelets, primefaces

PrimeFaces Datatable Column Sorting is not working in IE8 but it works fine in Firefox.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 17 Feb 2011 17:56:48 UTC

Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
jquery.js.jsf
Line: 23
Char: 21078
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/PrimeFacesTutorial/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

You might have:

```
<h:form id="form1"> 
.....
<h:form id="form2">
...
</h:form>
...
</h:form>
```

I got the same error, I remove the nested Form. I removed Form2 and it worked fine.