# after filtering Empty rows blank rows displayed while paging in the datatable using Primefaces

Tags: jsf, datatable, facelets, primefaces

I have problem with datatable using Primefaces 2.2.1 and JSF 2.0.

I have used filtering and paging in the datatable. When I try to filter the selected data is displayed and when i remove the filter the entire data is displayed. But after this when i try to use paging then suddendly all the rows becomes blank(empty) 
See screenshot below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions. Please help.

.xhtml file

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userManagedBean.searchUsersResults}"
        selection="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single"
        dynamic="true"
        onRowSelectUpdate="userUpdateForm"
        onRowUnselectUpdate="userUpdateForm"
        rowSelectListener="#{userManagedBean.onUserSelect}"
        rowUnselectListener="#{userManagedBean.onUserUnselect}"
        paginator="true" rows="10" style="width: 70% ">
        <p:column sortBy="#{user.userId}" filterBy="#{user.userId}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{user.username}" filterBy="#{user.username}">
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{user.emailId}" filterBy="#{user.emailId}">
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Email" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.emailId}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{user.dob}" filterBy="#{user.dob}">
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="DOB" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{user.dob}" >
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:panel id="userDetailsPanelId" header="Users Details" style="width:60%;">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2" id="userUpdateForm" border="0" >
            <h:outputLabel for="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.userId}" value="UserId"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.userId}" style="width: 100%;" readonly="true"></h:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel for="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.username}" value="Username"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.username}" readonly="true"></h:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel for="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.emailId}" value="EmailId"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.emailId}" readonly="true"></h:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel for="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.gender}" value="Gender"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.gender}" readonly="true"></h:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel for="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.dob}" value="DOB"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{userManagedBean.selectedUser.dob}" readonly="true">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            </h:inputText>

        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem and eventually discovered it was caused by my value object (in this case your user object) not implementing Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this known issue has been resolved in both the 2.2.RC and the 2.2 final.  I suggest updating your jar file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i m already using primefaces-2.2.1.jar which is available on the primefaces website. Have you got any other web urls links to get to "the 2.2.RC and the 2.2 final". Please suggest.

Comment: Nope, your correct, that's the most recent release according their site.  You may want to try the PrimeFaces support forum, or report this as a bug to PrimeFaces.

Comment: Yes. I have reported it in the PrimeFaces but still no luck. http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7931

Comment: Hi Sean, can you look into this question if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033224/primefaces-datatable-column-sorting-is-not-working-in-ie8-but-it-works-fine-in-fi